# Adding Pagination in View function not showing in template

Tags: python, django, pagination

I am trying to add pagination to a list of notifications in a function, so I added Paginator in the function following the documentation in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/pagination/#using-paginator-in-a-view-function, but there is no pagination showing in the template.
views.py:

```
def ShowNotifications(request):
    user=request.user
    notifications= Notification.objects.filter(user=user).order_by('-date')
    template= loader.get_template('notifications/notifications.html')
    paginator = Paginator(notifications, 1) # Show 1 Notification per page.

    page_number = request.GET.get('page')
    page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)

    context = {
        'notifications': notifications,
        'page_obj': page_obj
    }

    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

here is the pagination html

```
<!--Pagination-->
{% if is_paginated %}
<nav class="d-flex justify-content-center wow fadeIn">
    <ul class="pagination pg-blue">
        <!--Arrow left-->
        {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
        <li class="page-item">
            <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}" aria-label="Previous">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        {% endif %}
        <li class="page-item active">
            <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ page_obj.number}}">{{ page_obj.number}}
                <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        {% if page_obj.has_next %}
        <li class="page-item">
            <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}" aria-label="Next">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        {% endif %}
    </ul>
</nav>
{% endif %}
<!--Pagination-->
```

I have used the same pagination html in a List View and it worked, so this is the first time to add it in a function.

My question: What am I doing wrong that prevents pagination from appearing?

How do I fix it? I am in learning phase so a bit of explanation could be useful.

Comment: Try this: `page_number = request.GET.get('page', 1) ` . It will set the page number to `1` if the page query is not found.

Comment: @AjayLingayat nothing happened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My error is that I was not using `page_obj` when Looping through the obj should be in this way:

```
{% for contact in page_obj %}
    {# Each "contact" is a Contact model object. #}
    {{ contact.full_name|upper }}<br>
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

Thank you